# Jquery Date in GridView?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

> I have included the jquery datepicker inside the item template, if I
>   select the date from datepicker in the second row textbox
>   (tbxEffectiveFromDate), selected date has been stored in the
>   first row textbox only not in the selected Grid row index. Kindly
>   resolves this jquery datepicker in the grid view. If I mentioned the
>   textbox class name, it's not working.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvBaseTarget" runat="server" CssClass="gvBaseTarget">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="18%" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvBaseTargetLeft" HeaderText="Effective From" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvBaseTargetLeft">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxEffectiveFromDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ClientIDMode='Static' Enabled="false" Width="100px"   CssClass="tbxBaseTarget"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
 $(document).ready(function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindPicker);
            bindPicker();
        });

        function bindPicker() 
        {
            var $gv = $("table[id$=gvBaseTarget]");
            var $rows = $("> tbody > tr:not(:has(th, table))", $gv);
            var $inputs = $("[id*=tbxEffectiveFromDate]", $rows);
            $inputs.datepicker();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't that same ID **tbxEffectiveFromDate** getting repeated on your page? Try using the class **tbxBaseTarget** instead.

Answer (score 0):

`ClientIDMode='Static'` It will create all the textboxes with same id `tbxEffectiveFromDate`. That could be the cause of problem.

Try with removing `ClientIDMode='Static'` from your code.